# what is the difference between below two statements in application.properties file in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, application.properties

what is the difference between below two statements in application.properties file in spring boot.

server.port =8080
and
server.port = ${PORT:8080}

please help with the explanation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `server.port = ${PORT:8080}` will check for an environment variable `PORT` and take its value , if not present defaults to `8080`.
2. `server.port =8080` will always be `8080`